# What is the difference between $8\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} \bmod 8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

What is the difference between $8\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\bmod8$? I think I have $\mathbb{Z}\pmod8$ written as $\mathbb{Z}_8$ as well.

I know that $8\mathbb{Z}$ consists of {...-16, -8, 0, 8, 16, ...} and that $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is modular arithmetic which consists of {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7} and that $16 \equiv 8 \equiv 0 \pmod8$.

Is there anything else I am missing or not understanding?

Comment: $8\mathbb Z$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb Z$, whereas $\mathbb Z_8$ is a ring (or group, I guess, depending on the context) with $8$ elements. However, if you take the quotiont $\mathbb Z / 8\mathbb Z$ you get something that is "isomorphic" to $\mathbb Z_8$, but again, this depends on the context you are working in.

Comment: Exactly what the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_8$ might be is a matter of definition, but it has $8$ elements, whereas $8\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite. They are connected in that $\mathbb{Z}_8\cong\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $\Bbb Z_8$ has a number of different ways it could be formally defined.  In one of those ways it would be as $\{8\Bbb Z, 8\Bbb Z+1, 8\Bbb Z+2,\dots, 8\Bbb Z+7\}$... so your question of what's the difference between $\Bbb Z_8$ and $8\Bbb Z$?  The same difference between $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $3$... the one is a set containing the other.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!

Comment: $8\Bbb Z$ is an element (more precisely, the zero element) of $\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$